# Probability of winning a baseball game

Tags: probability

Ok so here is my question.  If the Tigers (team A) win 66% of the games they play on Tuesdays and the Sharks (team B) win 55% of the games they play on Tuesdays.  Now when they play each other on a Tuesday what are the true chances of each team winning since they  both cannot win?

Are these events considered disjoint events even though they are playing each other on a Tuesday?

Comment: whats your thoughs on this?

Comment: The only way I was thinking about this was by using manipulatives.  I figured that the .45 of Team B losing would be of benefit to Team A somehow. I was thinking getting one jar and putting in 66 red marbles that represent the chances of A winning and adding 45 more red for the B team losing which is the same as Team A winning and then adding 34 blue marbles for Team A losing which is the same as Team B winning and 55 blue for team B winning. Then 111/200 gives 55% which was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to find an answer without making unreasonable assumptions.  It is conceivable that in this type of game, the "better" team always wins.

So let us make **unreasonable** assumptions. One possible model is that each team tosses a coin that has the appropriate probability of landing "heads." We calculate the probability that A's coin lands heads, **given** that exactly one coin landed heads.

The probability exactly one coin landed heads is $(0.66)(0.45)+(0.34)(0.55)$. It follows by the usual defining formula for conditional probability that the probability A's coin landed heads, given exactly one did, is $\frac{(0.66)(0.45)}{(0.66)(0.45)+(0.34)(0.55)}$.

**Remark:** If A and B are playing each other on a Wednesday, the events "A wins" and "B wins" are disjoint. That, however, is of no significant help in computing the probability that A wins.

Comment: baynes theory here?